# Reference Request Scott's Trick

Tags: reference-request, set-theory

Does anyone know of a reference for Scott's Trick. I can't find it in Set Theory-Jech?

Comment: What exactly are you looking for it? I wrote at least one account of the trick on this site (maybe more?). (Also, I didn't downvote.)

Comment: I was just looking for somewhere that I could read about it, preferably a textbook. I thought it would be in Jech (maybe it is?) but I couldn't find it anywhere. thanks for the response

Comment: Yes, but what sort of reference are you looking for and why? Do you want to understand it? Do you want to reference in your text? The trick itself is wonderful, but it's really simple to understand once you're familiar with the axioms, so there's no much to read about here.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Thanks. I wanted to read about it (I don't really know how it is done) in a way that I can reference it (preferably not a forum) Thank you-sorry I am being unclear

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scott's trick is explained in Thomas Forster's book:

> Thomas Forster, **Logic, Induction and Sets**. Cambridge University Press, 2003

In particular, Section 8.6 is of interest regarding Scott's trick.

---

The trick itself is not difficult. The universe is based on a cumulative hierarchy, $V_\alpha$ and we can assign ranks to a set: the rank of $x$ is the least ordinal $\alpha$ such that $x\in V_{\alpha+1}$.

Now given any definable class (e.g. "all the sets equipotent with $x$") Scott's trick suggests that we take only those of minimal rank in the class. This is a set because it's a definable subset of a particular $V_\alpha$.

Note that this makes a very heavy use of the axiom of regularity.

Comment: BTW Forster's book is also given as a reference in the Wikipedia article on [Scott's trick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scott%27s_trick).

Answer (score 2):

Indeed it is included in Jech's book, but it is not attributed to Scott. This is from *Set Theory, The Third Millennium Edition, revised and expanded*, page 65:

> Given a class $C$, let
>   $$ (6.4)\qquad\qquad \hat C = \{x \in C : (\forall z \in C)\ \text{rank}\:x \leq \text{rank}\: z\}.  $$
>   $\hat C$ is always a set, and if $C$ is nonempty, then $\hat C$ is nonempty. Moreover, (6.4) can be applied uniformly.

After that, some examples and consequences are given. This is what's commonly known as Scott's trick.